# CARTO.js changing the styling only on one segment of a line with multiple segments

Tags: javascript, carto, carto-js

I'm attempting to change the styling of a line segment when clicked on a layer that has 4 segments. Only one segment's style would be changed at a time. Each segment has it's own column within a CARTO dataset. I was wondering if it was possible to accomplish this using only one dataset and not creating separate datasets for each segment? As of now when a line segment is clicked, all segments get the new styling applied.

Example of what I am trying to accomplish:

[image]

Below is the code I am using to change the styling:

```
routeLayer.on('featureClicked', featureEvent => {
  routeStyle.setContent(`
    #layer {
        line-width: 6;
        line-color: #c1d82f;
        line-opacity: 1;
     }
  `);
});
```

[JSFiddle example.](https://jsfiddle.net/Hysteresis/1dcw5L9v/3/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved my issue using CartoCSS conditional styling.

```
routeLayer.on('featureClicked', featureEvent => {
  console.log(featureEvent.data.name);
  routeStyle.setContent(`
    #layer {
      line-width: 6;
      line-color: #0067b1;
      line-opacity: 1;

      [name = '` + featureEvent.data.name + `']{
        line-width: 6;
        line-color: #c1d82f;
        line-opacity: 1;
      }
    }
  `);
});
```